# square alignment of prepositions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I would like to mirror this format of alignment, looks like a matrix but has no brackets.

maybe start a column exception?

[image: Final result:]

Comment: Is it only about the alignment or also about the content? Because the alignment is simply a `\begin{array}{*{4}{cl}}` or similar.

Comment: @campa ty hehe I'm new to LaTeX, about the content I've managed to do '''\textcircled{\raisebox{-0.9pt}{etc}}''' , mhm, but how would I sort them through the columns? I only know of arrays like \[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} x \\ y\\ z \end{array} \right)\] and such

Comment: Does this help? [Auto-numbering table environment with aligned numbers](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/209828). BTW, what do you mean by 'prepositions' (*Präposition* auf Deutsch)?

Comment: @AlanMunn yeah I'm not really looking for a table but ty, and unfortunately it's not from german xD well a mathematical preposition would be x>0, 2 isn't a prime number... I get lost at titles hehe

Comment: @BrunoStühler An `array` is simply a table in math. So you can do everything in the linked answer with `array` just as easily. Then I think you mean 'proposition' not 'preposition'.

Comment: 'Preposition'  é *preposição* em Portuguese. So I guess you mean 'proposition' not 'preposition'.

Comment: @AlanMunn Can I make the numbering of each item of the table circled? I might just find another question format.. then,  well, I'm a portuguese speaker, indeed  I see your point, I agree, though when I googled for 'preposition in mathematics' some sites would display as if it was the proposition meaning, maybe it falls in common sense... :)

Comment: If you're using this for exam/worksheet questions, then perhaps the `tasks` package might be of some help. There are various ways to make circled numbers. See [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032)

Comment: @AlanMunn yes I'm using \textcircled{\raisebox{-0.9pt}{0}} from that thread, so can I do a table without numbering? i.e., 1), 2).. and using only that command instead?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this is what you want. Adapted from the answers linked in the comments. (The one about numbering used the `tabu` package, which I don't recommend, and it's not relevant to the numbering issue.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{cellnum}
\renewcommand{\thecellnum}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt}{\arabic{cellnum}}}}

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{cellnum}\makebox[1em][r]{\thecellnum}\hspace{0.5em}}l}
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{\setcounter{cellnum}{-1}} % set to 0 to start at 1



\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{NNNN}
  2   & 5 & -2 & -5 \\ 
  a \geqq 2 & a \geqq 3 & a \geqq 4
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{NNNN}
  2   & 5 & -2 & -5 \\ 
  a \geqq 2 & a \geqq 3 & a \geqq 4
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]